# Is there a "best" tokenization for NER training in OpenNLP?

Tags: nlp, training-data, opennlp, named-entity-recognition

Is there a "best" tokenization for NER training in OpenNLP? I noticed that OpenNLP provides a max-entropy tokenizer that allows you to tokenize based on a trained model. I also noticed that OpenNLP provides a simple tokenizer. If I use the same tokenizer during runtime that I used to train my model, does it matter which tokenizer I use?

I would rather use the simple tokenizer for my application.

Answer (score 0):

For most applications the quality of your tokenizer isn't very important and as long as you use the same one in training and after you should be fine.

However, the only way to be sure is to try the different tokenizers and compare the results - for some applications the difference between a good tokenizer and a great one may matter.